# Is it ok to include files into a header file

Tags: c

Is it a common practice to include header files into another header file like this:

```
#ifndef _IO_H_
#define _IO_H_
#include <stdint.h> //Is this OK?
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t PIN0 :1;
   uint8_t PIN1 :1;
   uint8_t PIN2 :1;
   uint8_t PIN3 :1;
   uint8_t PIN4 :1;
   uint8_t PIN5 :1;
   uint8_t PIN6 :1;
   uint8_t PIN7 :1;
}pin_map;
#endif /*_IO_H_*/
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099271/including-files-in-header-vs-implementation-file-c

Comment: BTW the "include guards" `#ifndef _IO_H_`, `#define _IO_H_` and `#endif /*_IO_H_*/` are there specifically to make it possible to include header files into other header files. I guess your `stdint.h` file [contains such include guards too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8483955/509868) - if no (extremely unlikely), it's dangerous to do `#include <stdint.h>` in your header file.

Comment: note : `_IO_H_` corresponds to the reserved name. So This is illegal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's very common.

Some say it's a bad idea, but I don't agree since obviously the header you're writing *needs* `<stdint.h>` and it's quite rude (and very complicated for larger code) to require the user of the header to figure that out.

That said, of course you should never include headers that you don't need, since that contributes to both confusion and build times, both of which are bad and should be minimized.

Comment: In addition, avoid including any unnecessary header files in the following situation: when `file.h` is the public header for `file.c` and `file.c` uses, for example, some math, include `math.h` only in the source file and not in the header.